# Invalid block tag: 'pay_pal', expected 'endblock' or 'endblock content'

Tags: python, django, django-templates

does anyone has an idea about this and how can i deal with it?

> Invalid block tag: 'pay_pal', expected 'endblock' or 'endblock content'

in my `views.py`, i have this

```
pay_pal = get_integration("pay_pal")
pay_pal.add_fields({
       "business": "test@gmail.com",
       "item_name": product.name,
       "invoice": inst.id,
       "notify_url": settings.BASE_DNS + "/paypal-ipn-handler/",
       "return_url": settings.BASE_DNS + str(client.id) + '/book/'+str(inst.id) +'/success/?booksaved=1',
       "cancel_return": settings.BASE_DNS + str(client.id) + '/?booksaved=0',
       "amount": inst.totalcost})
return render_to_response("pay_pay.html", {"obj": pay_pal},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and in my template, `pay_pay.html`, i have this :

```
{% extends "main_base_bookingpage.html" %}
{% block bodyclass %}product-add{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Pay here!</h1>
{% load billing_tags %} 
{% pay_pal obj %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What paypal library are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably, you have to move `{% load billing_tags %}` to the top of the `pay_pay.html`.

Comment: thanks for the reply Alexander, i try to move it on the top of pay_pay.html but it wont work, it has the same problem...

Comment: Then, obviously, there is no block named `pay_pal` in the `billing_tags` templatetags library.

Comment: @AlexanderArtemenko: s/block/tag/

Comment: i get it now Alexander, i got this error because i have .ve in my django, and the pay_pal were installed in the main directory. so i re-install the pay_pal to my .ve and i try your answer and it works, thanks alexander